# How do I uninstall dart sass?

Tags: ruby, sass, dart, uninstallation

i'm having trouble figuring out how to uninstall Dart Sass, I'm starting to use Sass but every tutorial out there is in Ruby Sass, and since Dart Sass is the one they're actually distributing in their homepage I installed that one without knowing anything, the problem started when I couldn't do this simple:

```
sass --watch sass:css
```

Because it says " Could not find an option named "watch" ".I couldn't find anyway to do that in Dart Sass so I decided to install Ruby Sass, but now my cmd prompt in windows recognizes the Ruby Sass version but my Atom prompt recognizes Dart's and doesn't get the commands, so I want to uninstall Dart's but I don't find anywhere how to do it.

I'm using Dart Sass 1.3.1, installed via Chocolatey on Windows x64.

Hope you can help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried this command?

```
$ choco uninstall sass -prerelease
```

btw `dart-sass` currently doesn't support `watch` command:
[Support CLI watcher and mtime-aware updater #264](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/264)